# DynamicRouteValueTransformer does not exist

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I get a missing reference error when I try to inherit from the class DynamicRouteValueTransformer in a class library but when I do it from my MVC app it works fine.

```
public class ProductRouteTransformer : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.DynamicRouteValueTransformer
```

*DynamicRouteValueTransformer* is in namespace *Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing* which is part of *Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll*. I've added the DLL to the class library using Nuget and can see that it is installed but I still get a missing reference error. The class is just missing from the namespace.

I'm using .NET Core 3.1.

The csproj is below:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="9.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core" Version="2.2.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing" Version="2.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog" Version="4.6.8" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Database\EntityUtils\" />
  </ItemGroup>


</Project>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a topic in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#use-the-aspnet-core-shared-framework) that was introduced recently, which covers this in great detail:

> With the release of .NET Core 3.0, many ASP.NET Core assemblies are no longer published to NuGet as packages.

If you take a look at the contents of your .csproj, you'll see that you've added references to `2.2.x` versions of a few `Microsoft.AspNetCore.*` packages. I'm sure you intended to reference `3.1.x` versions of these, but, as the docs quote above shows, these packages are no longer produced for 3.0+.

The next few lines from the docs explain what's happened here:

> Instead, the assemblies are included in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` shared framework, which is installed with the .NET Core SDK and runtime installers.
>
> As of .NET Core 3.0, projects using the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` MSBuild SDK implicitly reference the shared framework. Projects using the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk` or `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor` SDK must reference ASP.NET Core to use ASP.NET Core APIs in the shared framework.

As your project is referencing `Microsoft.NET.Sdk`, you'll need to add a `FrameworkReference`, as described above, and remove those old `PackageReference`s:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="9.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog" Version="4.6.8" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Database\EntityUtils\" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Note that not *all* of the packages have been folded into the shared framework. For example, `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` is still provided as a NuGet package.